# IP passthrough when using NGINX as an SSL Proxy

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy

I've got nginx configured to do SSL termination for an apache webserver.  It seems to be working, however all requests going to the webserver appear to be coming from the nginx server and not the original ip address.  Is it possible for those to come through intact?

Answer (score 2):

Sure it's possible.

Just install [mod_rpaf](http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/). Configure apache as follows:

```
LoadModule rpaf_module libexec/apache2/mod_rpaf-2.0.so

RPAFenable On
RPAFsethostname On
RPAFproxy_ips 127.0.0.1 10.0.0.1
RPAFheader X-Forwarded-For
```

Where RPAFproxy_ips are the IP address(es) of your nginx reverse proxy.

Nginx needs to be configured to set the `X-Forwarded-For` header as well:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```